# filter on spark timestamp doesn't work in range bigger than a day

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am working with pyspark 2.3.0 version .
i am filtering a dataframe on a timestamp column .

|-- requestTs: timestamp (nullable = true)

when i filter on a inter-day time range it works great .
when i span the filter on 2 days range it doesn't return all records.
i tried few ways like :

```
        df1 = df.filter(df["requestts"] >= sqlf.lit(startDatestr)) \
           .filter(df["requestts"] <= sqlf.lit(endDatestr))
```

or

```
        dates = (startDatestr, endDatestr)

        q1 = "unix_timestamp(requestts) BETWEEN unix_timestamp('{0}', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') AND unix_timestamp('{1}', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')".format(
            *dates)

        df1 = df.where(q1)
```

where

```
startDatestr: 2018-06-26 07:00:00
endDatestr: 2018-06-26 21:40:00
```

when i count the returned records i get

```
after date filter, count is :1168940768
```

if i expand the search(so i expect larger or equal number of records) like :

```
startDatestr: 2018-06-25 11:00:00
endDatestr: 2018-06-26 21:40:00
```

i get much fewer number of records .

i am puzzeled what could be the reason for that and what is the best way to filter by timestamp.
and how i take the timezone also into consideration .

Answer (score 4):

Your query should work. I just tried it on the pyspark shell.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

>>> columns = ['id', 'ts']
>>> vals = [
...     (1, datetime(2018, 6, 26)),
...     (2, datetime(2018, 6, 27)),
...     (3, datetime(2018, 6, 28)),
...     (4, datetime(2018, 6, 29)),
...     (5, datetime(2018, 6, 30))
... ]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

>>> df.show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|                 ts|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2018-06-26 00:00:00|
|  2|2018-06-27 00:00:00|
|  3|2018-06-28 00:00:00|
|  4|2018-06-29 00:00:00|
|  5|2018-06-30 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ts: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Here is a query similar to yours:

```
>>> df.filter(df['ts'] >= F.lit('2018-06-27 00:00:00')) \
...     .filter(df['ts'] < F.lit('2018-06-29 00:00:00')).show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|                 ts|
+---+-------------------+
|  2|2018-06-27 00:00:00|
|  3|2018-06-28 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

You can also use a logical operator to do two filter at once:

```
>>> df.filter((df['ts'] >= F.lit('2018-06-27 00:00:00'))
...           & (df['ts'] < F.lit('2018-06-29 00:00:00'))).show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|                 ts|
+---+-------------------+
|  2|2018-06-27 00:00:00|
|  3|2018-06-28 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

Lastly, you don't really need the `lit` function. So you can just use string:

```
>>> df.filter((df['ts'] >= '2018-06-27 00:00:00')
...           & (df['ts'] < '2018-06-29 00:00:00')).show()
+---+-------------------+
| id|                 ts|
+---+-------------------+
|  2|2018-06-27 00:00:00|
|  3|2018-06-28 00:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```

For timezone, you can see the pyspark documentation of [from_unixtime function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime).
I have also pasted the example below for easier reference:

```
>>> spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/Los_Angeles")
>>> time_df = spark.createDataFrame([(1428476400,)], ['unix_time'])
>>> time_df.select(from_unixtime('unix_time').alias('ts')).collect()
[Row(ts='2015-04-08 00:00:00')]
>>> spark.conf.unset("spark.sql.session.timeZone")
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , yes , i did a test , like you described and i saw my code should work , that is why i don't understand why it doesn't , thought it could be because of time zones , or something related to time part , casting , etc.
the last example without the lit function was my original try , and it didn't work with cross day scenario .

Comment: what spark does is interpert the filter as :
Post-Scan Filters: isnotnull(requestts#409),(cast(requestts#409 as string) >= 2018-06-26 07:00:00),(cast(requestts#409 as string) <= 2018-06-26 15:40:00)

i wonder if this casting from timestamp to string , and string comparison is always working, isn't it better to cast to epoch time and compare integer to integer ?

Comment: I think the casting should be fine and well tested. Why don't you create a small example like I did and append your code in your original post?

Comment: my example worked so no need to write it here , wondered what changed from the example to the large scale test